# prepending numbers to a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to open a file, read the contents and then numbering the contents of that file and saving it. So for example the file contains:

```
This is line 1.

This is line 2.

This is line 3.
```

the output should be :

1. This is line 1.
2. This is line 2.
3. This is line 3.

I'm incredibly new to ruby so I've only gotten as far as adding the lines to an array. But now I don't know how to add numbers to each item of the array. Here is what I have:

```
class AddNumbers
  def insert_numbers_to_file(file)
    @file_array = []
    line_file = File.open(file)
    line_file.each do |line|
      @file_array << [line]
    end
  end
end
```

Any help or hints would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Does it work as you expect ? If not, what is the result that you get ?

Answer (score 1):

Enumerators have an `#each_with_index` method that you can use:

```
class AddNumbers
  def insert_numbers_to_file(file)
    @file_array = []
    File.open(file).each_with_index do |line, index|
      @file_array << "%d. %s" % [index, line]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: ah, thanks this is a good place to start! Now just to figure out how to start the index from 1 rather than 0 and actually write it to a the file.

Comment: so I declared the value of index to be 1 before the do loop and incremented it. This fixes the numbering issue, but how would I then take the output and replace the original file with it?

Comment: The easiest way will be to re-open the file in write mode (`open(file, 'w')`) and then write your @file_array buffer back to it (either by joining it with newlines, or iterating over it).

Answer (score 0):

The [magic variable $.](http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/English/rdoc/index.html) is your ticket to ride here:

```
class AddNumbers
  def insert_numbers_to_file(file)
    @file_array = []
    line_file = File.open(file)
    line_file.each do |line|
      @file_array << "#{$.}: #{line}"
    end
    @file_array
  end
end
```